# Unable to use DxTextBox in DxDropDown within OffCanvas

Tags: c#, off-canvas-menu, devexpress-blazor

I'm coding in C# using DevExpress Blazor, and I'm facing an issue where I can't input text when using DxTextBox and DxComboBox within DxDropdown placed inside an OffCanvas. However, checkboxes work fine. Below is an image of my web page: thecolored arrow represents DxDropdown, and inside it is DxTextBox. The blue arrow represents OffCanvas.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULaCW.png)

I tried moving DxDropdown outside of OffCanvas, and it worked fine.

Comment: Please add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or at least the code that is not working to your question.

Comment: Is the OffCanvas a DevExpress control?